# Webpack: how to check if custom index.js file exists and load it

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got this file structure:

```
src/
  MyComponent1/
    index.js
    index.custom.js
  MyComponent2/
    index.js
```

index.js and index.custom.js files in MyComponent1 folder contain different implementations of `MyComponent1`.

I'd like to load code of a component from `index.custom.js` file if this file exists in file system. Otherwise fallback to code from index.js.

```
// Should import src/MyComponent1/index.custom.js
import MyComponent1 from './MyComponent1';

// Should import src/MyComponent2/index.js
import MyComponent2 from './MyComponent2';
```

Is that possible? I'm using React with Webpack 3.

Comment: "MyComponent1 folder contain different versions of " sounds like you are trying to replace VCS with a file system.

Comment: As of the question take a look at https://webpack.js.org/api/resolvers/ You might need to implement your own plugin that does the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but according to [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfiles) you could configure resolver to use custom index file names.

Adding this to webpack config should do the trick.

```
resolve: {
  ...
  mainFiles: [ "index.custom", "index" ]
}
```